# How does the Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI) compute the Magnetic Activity Index (MAI)?

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-sun

I am looking for a description about how this number called Magnetic Activity Index (MAI) is calculated. All I know is that the processing pipeline of the [instrument HMI](http://hmi.stanford.edu/) calculates it. But I would like to know *how* this quantity is defined and computed! I have not yet found anything on google about it, not even an article.

Comment: Is this the HMI you are refering to ? http://hmi.stanford.edu/

Comment: Yes it is! I visited this website, but the magnetic activity index is not mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I found a quote from [**K. Jain *et al.***](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224934523_Subsurface_Flows_in_and_Around_Active_Regions_with_Rotating_andNon-rotating_Sunspots)  which **defines a Magnetic Activity Index** might be pointing you in the correct direction - for me it still sounds rather abstract:

> To obtain the MAI, we convert magnetogram data to absolute values, average over the length of a ring day and [apodise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodization) them into circular areas to match the size of the [Dopplergram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopplergraph) patches used in the ring-diagram analysis.

However, I also found http://hmi.stanford.edu/teams/rings/modules/maicalc.html which contains a link a source code repository. The man-page of **maicalc** states:

> maicalc takes as its input a dataset of records representing solar magnetograms during a selected interval, and produces as its output the values of the Magnetic Activity Index (MAI) appropriate for a selected set of target locations as they would be mapped and tracked by mtrack for the duration of the input data interval and apodized by pspec3.